# SQL API or Fusion Tables searching

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I want to search my table in each column I choose. What am I doing wrong?

this is work
`SELECT * FROM TABLE_ID WHERE firstname LIKE '%"+ s +"%' ORDER BY id DESC OFFSET "+ start +" LIMIT "+ localStorage.getItem('delimeter'))`

this is not
`SELECT * FROM TABLE_ID WHERE firstname LIKE '%"+ s +"%' OR lastname LIKE '%"+ s +"%' ORDER BY id DESC OFFSET "+ start +" LIMIT "+ localStorage.getItem('delimeter'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fusion Table API does not support the 'OR' SQL operator, only 'AND'.
You could run two queries and combine the results in the client.

Comment: two queries is the only way to replace the `OR` ?